# How to only query the results of `time` parameter (without other data values) in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

If I only want to query `time` in a time series without querying other parameters in Apache IoTDB, are there any query method that can directly return these results? The reason why I want to ask about this method is because I have a database that stores binary data. If I query with the value of the time series, currently it will take a long time. Therefore I would like to ask if there is a way to check only the `time` in Apache IoTDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no way to check only the `time` column value, because the time stored are attached to a time series in Apache IoTDB. If your binary data stored is very large, you can set up a new time series and only use this series to store the time value, for example, to name it `ts`, so you can query this time series for the time values and it will be easy for you to remember this time series name.